# 100+ фрагментов или Single Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, архитектура

Всем привет, разрабатываю просто огроменный проект - Android клиент для одной игры. Пока что делаю API часть, но скоро приступлю к интерфейсу. Так вот, вопрос, игра большая и экранов будет очень много (100 штук точно). Как лучше организовать: на фрагментах или все держать на одной активности, но разделить их с MVP архитектурой на экраны-View?

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно дать однозначно ответ, потому что использовать тот или иной компонент, зависит от реализации, после надо знать, что этот UI будет показывать, где он будет использоваться, будет ли другая ориентация, какая будет навигация, как будут сделаны переходы и тд и уж точно не понять это по количеству экранов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лучше всего совместить несколько активити с несколькими фрагментами в них, разбив приложение на активити по принципу разделения логики приложения на части.

Например отдельную активити для логина - в ней будет несколько фрагментов для собственно входа, профиля, восстановления пароля etc.

В ещё одной активити может быть список игровых комнат, чатов etc. В третьей - собственно игра.

Comment: Все портит боковое меню. Мне придется создавать его на каждой активности. Ну ок, спасибо, сделаю так :)

Comment: @Flippy, это не проблема - просто сделайте базовую активити, в разметке коей будет это меню, а в коде - соответствующий код. После каждую активити наследуйте от этой. Я так делал и всё отлично работает)

Comment: Да, да, с опытом я понял, что все просто и копипастить не надо: обычное наследование :)